# Как в php отсортировать двумерный ассоциативный массив в зависимости от параметра?

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть двумерный ассоциативный массив в **php**.

```
$array = array(
  '37' => array(
    'term_id'  => '37',
    'name'   => 'BMW',
    'slug'   => 'bmw',
     'count' => '3',
  ),
  '22' => array(
    'term_id'  => '22',
    'name'   => 'Mercedes',
    'slug'   => 'Mercedes',
     'count' => '2',
  ),
  '18' => array(
    'term_id'  => '18',
    'name'   => 'Honda',
    'slug'   => 'honda',
     'count' => '6',
  ),
  '51' => array(
    'term_id'  => '51',
    'name'   => 'Alfa Romeo',
    'slug'   => 'alfa-romeo',
  ),
  '90' => array(
    'term_id'  => '90',
    'name'   => 'Tesla',
    'slug'   => 'tesla',
     'count' => '1',
  )
);
```

Мне нужно отсортировать его по возрастанию в зависимости от параметра `count` внутри элементов, причем самого параметра может и не быть, тогда оставлять элементы в том же порядке для последующего вывода.

Не могу понять, как правильно вставить массив в определенную позицию

```
$buff_array = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if($item->count) {
        $buff_array = array_splice( $buff_array, $count, 0, $item );
    }
    else {
        $buff_array[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php или https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php

Comment: делаю так `uasort( $array, fn($item1, $item2) => ($item1['count'] ?? 0) <=> ($item2['count'] ?? 0));` но, элементы с нулем остаются вверху списка, хотя мне нежны снизу

Comment: Если вам нужна сортировка в другом направлении, поменяйте порядок аргументов в замыкании (`$item2, $item1`)

Answer (score 0):

При таком решении у меня все полностью заработало

```
   uasort(
        $array,
        function ($item1, $item2) {
            if (!isset($item1['count']) && !isset($item2['count'])) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (!isset($item1['count'])) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (!isset($item2['count'])) {
                return -1;
            }
            if ($item1['count'] == $item2['count']) {
                return 1;
            }
            return $item1['count'] - $item2['count'];
        }
    );
```

Если честно, сам не понял почему понадобилось условие с возвратом 1, а не нуля, но, именно в этом случае при равенстве счетчиков, равные элементы остаются на своих местах и не меняют своих позиций

```
if ($item1['count'] == $item2['count']) {
            return 1;
        }
```